# Does sorting switch cases by probability of match improve efficiency?

Tags: c, switch-statement

Suppose we read various characters. If we know that there will be more a's than g's, will this be more efficient

```
for (int i = 0; buffer[i]; ++i) {

    switch(buffer[i]) {
        case 'a': //do something
            break;

        case 'g': //do something else
           break;
    }
}
```

than putting case g first and case a second?

Edit:
I'm talking about time efficiency. I know that even it there was an improvement, it would be insignificant. I'm just curious.

Comment: efficient? as less heat generated by computer running the code ... or as less space in the executable ... or what? :-) Anyway: it is not going to matter, but **measure** (whatever you want *efficiency* to mean) on your computer and draw your conclusions

Comment: Far too broad. Depends how the switch is converted to code. For a switch with adjascent cases, likely not on most CPUs, for other it might. (It might also depend on the optimization settings, heuristics, etc.). **Do not make premature optimizations, concentrate on readability.** Only after you **really** have timing issues, profile your working code (with all optimizations enabled!), then optimize the identified remaining bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

What code the `switch` control structure yields depends on what the concrete `case` values are and which compiler you use.

But the order of the cases doesn't matter. The result will always be the same, no matter whether the `case` labels are ordered ascendingly, randomly, or descendingly. It's solely up to you how it serves you best.

A good compiler will decide it between using jump table or chained `if-else`. 
If value as close it will use jump table , if not then chained `if-else` and a binary search.

So , IMHO it should depend on compiler.